# Spark: spark-csv takes too long

Tags: csv, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to create a `DataFrame` from a CSV source that is on S3 on an EMR Spark cluster, using the Databricks [spark-csv](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv) package and the [flights dataset](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-2/wiki/Hacking-Airline-DataSet-with-H2O):

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

df = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='true').load('s3n://h2o-airlines-unpacked/allyears.csv')

df.first()
```

This does not terminate on a cluster of 4 `m3.xlarge`s. I am looking for suggestions to create a `DataFrame` from a CSV file on S3 in PySpark. Alternatively, I have tried putting the file on HDFS and reading from HFDS as well, but that also does not terminate. The file is not overly large (12 GB).

Comment: If spark-csv lib is 1.2.0+ version, can you try with `parserLib` option set to `univocity`?

Comment: @rchukh Isn't that the default? Have built the jar from the master today. EDIT: No, it is not. Will try that.

Answer (score 1):

For reading a well-behaved csv file that is only 12GB, you can copy it onto all of your workers and the driver machines, and then manually split on ",".  This may not parse any RFC4180 csv, but it parsed what I had.

- Add at least 12GB extra space for worker disk space for each worker when you requisition the cluster.
- Use a machine type that has at least 12GB RAM, such as `c3.2xlarge`.  Go bigger if you don't intend to keep the cluster around idle and can afford the larger charges.  Bigger machines means less disk file copying to get started.  I regularly see c3.8xlarge under $0.50/hour on the spot market.

copy the file to each of your workers, in the same directory on each worker.  This should be a physically attached drive, i.e. different physical drives on each machine.

Make sure you have that same file and directory on the driver machine as well.

```
raw = sc.textFile("/data.csv")

print "Counted %d lines in /data.csv" % raw.count()

raw_fields  = raw.first()
# this regular expression is for quoted fields. i.e. "23","38","blue",...
matchre = r'^"(.*)"$'
pmatchre = re.compile(matchre)

def uncsv_line(line):
    return [pmatchre.match(s).group(1) for s in line.split(',')]

fields = uncsv_line(raw_fields)

def raw_to_dict(raw_line):
    return dict(zip(fields, uncsv_line(raw_line)))

parsedData = (raw
        .map(raw_to_dict)
        .cache()
        )

print "Counted %d parsed lines" % parsedData.count()
```

parsedData will be a RDD of dicts, where the keys of the dicts are the CSV field names from the first row, and the values are the CSV values of the current row. If you don't have a header row in the CSV data, this may not be right for you, but it should be clear that you could override the code reading the first line here and set up the fields manually.

Note that this is not immediately useful for creating data frames or registering a spark SQL table.  But for anything else, it is OK, and you can further extract and transform it into a better format if you need to dump it into spark SQL.

I use this on a 7GB file with no issues, except I've removed some filter logic to detect valid data that has as a side effect the removal of the header from the parsed data.  You might need to reimplement some filtering.

Comment: Paul, thanks for the comment, and I appreciate that you have tried to answer what I have asked. But would you suggest a different approach to this? Like reading in the CSV from HDFS into Hive first and creating the DataFrame from the Hive table? Given the infrastructure what is the best way to read in a 12 GB file as a DataFrame?

Comment: Sorry, we simply dont use the HDFS/Hive infrastructure here at this time so don't have an opinion.

Comment: Paul, could you please provide some specifics on how you might take an RDD of dicts and make a `DataFrame` out of it?

Comment: Use map and a lambda function to transform each dict to a value tuple of the desired values. Write the schema manually.  If you want all the values from each row it might be easier to change the parsing map to not use zip.  I have not run any of this but it seems plausible to me.

Comment: If you only need fast SQL you can also look at Google's proprietary hosted BigQuery.  It costs $5 per TB scanned plus like 2 cents per gb per month for storage.